# Laravel The stream or file "storage/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied in RHEL8

Tags: laravel, rhel8

I need help here. I installed Laravel in my RHEL 8 Server

But I'm getting this error. I know this question already posted many times but I tried to follow the suggestion but no luck for me so far. I have no idea why.

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/vpa/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

[image]
I tried to use this command to change the permission but it didn't work .

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache 
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache

sudo setenforce 0 
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage

php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload

sudo systemctl restart httpd
sudo reboot
```

Nothing seems to work on my side . I don't know what else to do. Please help me

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. I'm running my app on Nginx though. Anyway it's been some time. Have you been able to solve it on your own eventually?

Comment: I just managed to resolve my issue by running `setenforce 0`.

Comment: @KelvinLow. I found the solution in RHEL8 . You need to set chmod to 775 to folder storage and bootstrap/cache instead of 755. And yes , you need to 'setenforce 0'

Comment: Good to know. Do you mind answering your own question so that other people will know that your question has been answered?

Answer (score 17):

on ubuntu this step solved it

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/your_folder

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/www/your_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

sudo chmod +w storage/logs/laravel.log

Never use 777

Those are irresponsible permissions

Answer (score 1):

In my case, apart from ensuring all permissions were correct, I also had to disable SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

I had changed my storage permission by run following command.It works for me:

**step 1:**

> sudo chmod -R +rwX .

**step 2:**

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) .

Comment: Could you please add where you are? What is the path where you're executing those commands.

Comment: @Pathros Thank you for your query. Basically, I was working on a laravel project in visual studio code and I got that storage issue. And then I open the visual studio code *terminal and executed those commands and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage
find ./storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chown www-data:www-data ./bootstrap/cache -R
find ./bootstrap/cache -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .env
find .env -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Read/Write Permission Allow run this commnad

```
chmod -R 755 /storage/laravel.log”
```

Comment: Never recommend `777`. `755` is far better.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/*
sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/*
```

Comment: Never recommend `777`. `755` is far better.